# Variable expansion in shell script

Tags: shell

I am having some problem expanding a variable.

First I set the value of the key.

`KEY=Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=`

Then I tried calling it in curl but it was not working. To diagnose the problem, I decided to print the actual command that was being run. This was the result

`` print curl -H `print "Authorization: " $KEY` "http://192.168.1.1/userRpm/WlanMacFilterRpm.htm?Page=1&exclusive=0" ``

>> `http://192.168.1.1/userRpm/WlanMacFilterRpm.htm?Page=1&exclusive=0`

It was only printing the string after the KEY. Whereas, If I replaced it myself, it was printing the correct output.

`print curl -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" "http://192.168.1.1/userRpm/WlanMacFilterRpm.htm?Page=1&exclusive=0"`

>> `curl -H Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4= http://192.168.1.1/userRpm/WlanMacFilterRpm.htm?Page=1&exclusive=0`

Comment: Please read (again) a Bash tutorial, this is very basic stuff and you should have find the solution before posting here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am really sorry that this is a basic question. I will delete it very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the value in quotes because you have a space.

```
KEY="Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
```

Doing `KEY=Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=` without quotes is like assigning "Basic" to "KEY" and nothing to another variable called "YWRtaW46YWRtaW4".

Then simply use it like so:

```
curl -H "Authorization: $KEY" "http://192.168.1.1/userRpm/WlanMacFilterRpm.htm?Page=1&exclusive=0"
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have fixed the main problem, however, I am getting the key from another command. `KEY="$(curl -Ivs -X GET "http://admin:admin@192.168.1.1" &> >(awk '/^> Authorization/{ print $3 " " $4 }'))"` . How would I go about making it work with this?

Comment: You have to learn about process substitution, redirections and pipelines. Basically, you can assign the output of a command to a variable with `VAR=$(command)`. Here your command is redirecting its output in a file that is created with the output of another command. This will not work. I think what you want is a pipeline: `KEY="$(curl ... | awk ...)"`

Comment: I need to pipe the stderr and not (necessarily) the stdout. So `|` did not work. I can assure you that the command `curl -Ivs -X GET "http://admin:admin@192.168.1.1" &> >(awk '/^> Authorization/{ print $3 " " $4 }')` returns exactly the string that I want.

Comment: OK, my bad. But if your command works fine, then you have your key, so you have everything you need, no? Simply use the key in the second curl command :/ By the way, to pipe stdout + stderr, you can use `|&`.

Comment: The command works fine. I have the key too. But my router keeps on telling me that my auth header is invalid. Anyways, if you'd like here's my paste https://pastebin.com/yNCJeceQ

Comment: Well this is out of the scope of this thread. Search for a solution accordingly to the error you get, and if you really can't solve it, post a new question on SO ;)

Comment: No, unless you feel uncomfortable keeping it open.